# Some workflows may not be shown. We were unable to reach the workflow service. SharePoint 2013 workflows issue

Tags: sharepoint-server, designer

I am suddenly getting "Some workflows may not be shown. We were unable to reach the workflow service." error when trying to check on the workflows I created using SharePoint Designer 2013. I checked the backend service and it is running and I also checked the workflow service and it is running fine. I see an error in application event log "6398" "Unexpected exception in FeedCacheService.IsRepopulationNeeded: Failed to Decrypt data" but I'm not sure if this is related to our workflow service breaking. I am using SharePoint 2016.

Can any one suggest what should be done to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Central Administration> Application Management> Manage service applications> click the Workflow Service Application Proxy to check whether the Workflow Service Status is connected:

[image]

If the workflow is connected, go to the web application and check the service connection:

[image]

If not, re-register the workflow on both App and WFE servers to test again.

Comment: How does one "re-register the workflow on both App and WFE servers"?...